# Flex Mobile Drag and Drop List Items

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have been searching for a flex mobile drag and drop example for a list. Does anyone have an example on how this can be done.

Comment: Drag and Drop is not supported on mobile devices so far as I knew.  So, you'll have to roll your own somehow.  If you expand more on what you're trying to accomplish perhaps we can offer more assistance.

Comment: I am trying to take a list of images and drag one of the images into a area and get the source of the image i dropped.

Comment: What have you tried to make this work?  Thiscame up w/ a Google Search that may help: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/847677

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for Drag&Drop in Flex Mobile:

http://flexponential.com/2011/06/21/using-drag-and-drop-with-a-spark-list-in-a-mobile-flex-application/